# Quantos dias ficaremos em beta privado?

Tags: support, beta, private-beta

How many days will we be in private beta?  Is it some set number of days or  \is it something that will be determined by a "superior" decision (*SE team*, for example, will decide whether the private beta was successful)?

---

Quantos dias ficaremos em beta privado? Tem dias determinados ou é algo que será determinado por uma decisão "maior" (equipe do SE por exemplo irá decidir se o beta privado foi bem sucedido)?

Comment: I guess this is relevant http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158144/where-can-i-see-how-long-a-site-is-will-remain-in-private-beta Looks like the minimum is seven days, and I guess we'll hit that (since the beta has been quite strong). Might be nice to hear an official response, though.

Comment: Till the very first day Robert Cartaino come back from vacation, I guess :)

Comment: 8 days and nothing.. this is killing me.. Robert's still missing. I left a comment to Tim Post [here](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/44/is-there-a-cm-designated-to-be-responsible-for-the-community#comment393_49)

Comment: @Math "8 days" or "8 weeks"?

Comment: 8 days so far... hope it doesn't take the mysterious 8 weeks duration :)

Comment: [Robert Cartaino](http://stackexchange.com/users/34933/robert-cartaino?tab=accounts) doesn't even have an account here! OMG... It'll definitely take a while :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Quantos dias ficaremos em beta privado?

## Acabamos de entrar no beta público. :)

Ficamos no total 13 dias no beta privado.

Comment: Marquei como correta, pois pra mim é o mais lógico :)

Answer (score 10):

At least 7 days, but it will depend on how the private beta is going.

About an official response, [this answer from Chris W. Rea](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4455/137348) has been [edited by Robert Cartaino♦](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/4455/2) in a way that now it says (emphasis mine):

> I understand the typical private beta is at least 7 days, but
>   sometimes it gets extended if the private beta **does not yet have
>   their scope worked out** or it isn't yielding the kinds of metrics and
>   quality questions desired.

About the metrics, we always can check how is it going in the [Area51 Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language).

31.3 questions per day -> healthy beta
 94% answered -> healthy beta
 50 avid users -> we need 150 (100 more) users with 200+ rep, 10 with 2k+ rep, 5 with 3k+ rep
 1.5 answer ratio -> **we need more answers**
 273 visits/day -> 1500 needed, but that would come in open beta

But I guess the metrics are less important, if this site **does not yet have their scope worked out**.

In [this other answer](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5563/137348), Robert Cartaino♦ also stated (emphasis mine):

> Be careful about cracking open the text books and seeding the site
>   with questions that been asked on every other site on the subject.
>   **This isn't a trial, demonstration, nor a "call for questions" just to shore up your numbers. This is your actual site.**
>
> Please ask about problems you actually have.

A link in that answer to a post in the blog, [Asking the First Questions](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/07/area-51-asking-the-first-questions/), contains in my oppinion something very interesting (emphasis mine):

> It's All About Design
>
> Design doesn't just mean the obvious issues like designing the logo,
>   or picking colors, or coming up with a name, or writing the FAQ. **The
>   very act of asking questions, answering questions, tagging, voting...
>   everything. It's all about design.**
>
> That's why early participation is really, really important. Those
>   earliest questions on your site say a lot about the community. So, if
>   you want to ask question just for the sake of asking questions, at
>   least make them really good ones. Ask real, expert questions.
>
> *In short, you are going to get the site you build.*
>
> **Ask your first questions with an eye on the site's design. Those first questions will likely end up on the front page when potential
>   experts see your site for the first time. Make those first questions
>   exemplary questions that are worthy of imitation.**
>
> So, back to our quiz: "*What is the single most important design
>   element of a new Q&A site?*" The answer is obviously, "The questions
>   on the front page." Any other design issues after that are a distant
>   second.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Hopefully, language experts will be drawn in during the open beta and they'll raise the answer ratio. I don't think we should worry too much about that when we only have 200 users, most of whom are programmers and SE enthusiasts. As far as working out the scope goes, we only have one open meta question on that topic right now: http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition and I don't think that should hold us back.

Comment: Take a look at our [month questions](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/?tab=month) and compare it to [a graduated site](http://english.stackexchange.com/?tab=month). Obviously that's an unfair comparison, but it can give us some clues: what would we want in our front page? Anyway, I think it is going well for us.

Comment: I agree that it is going well, although I wish we had more answers per question.

Comment: Great answer. Just to note that the default case is now to let the private betas go the full **two weeks.** It used to be that we let them go a week with the optional second week if they needed it, but it was rare that one week was enough, so we switched over to a standard two-week private beta.

Answer (score 5):

## Site main indicators

For future comparison.

Current figures in [area51 Portuguese Language Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/64172/portuguese-language).

- Screen shot dated 2015-11-06:

[image]

---

`Date  (YYMMDD)  | 150722 | 150725 | 150728 | 150731 | 150815 | 151106 |`

`Days in beta    |    7   |    10  |    13  |    16  |    31  |   114  |`

`private/public  |          private         |           public   ->    |`

---

`Question/day    |   27.8 |   21.4 |   17.1 |    5.4 |    3.7 |    1.3 |`

`Answered  %     |    95  |    94  |    95  |    96  |     98 |     98 |`

---

`Total users     |   228  |   232  |    238 |    245 |    333 |    566 |`

`200+ rep users  |    50  |    52  |     53 |     53 |     65 |     76 |`

`2k+ rep users   |    -   |    -   |     -  |     -  |     -  |      8 |`

`3k+ rep users   |    -   |    -   |     -  |     -  |     -  |      2 |`

---

`Answer ratio    |    1.5 |    1.5 |    1.5 |    1.5 |    1.6 |    1.7 |`

---

`Visits/day      |    229 |    185 |    159 |    134 |    188 |    405 |`

- Screen shot dated 2015-08-15:

[image]

Comment: A fase beta pública começou em 2015-07-28, no 13º dia de existência deste site.

Answer (score 5):

It'll take between [**6 and 8**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/185667) weeks.
Being "weeks" a concept under industrial secret by the company.

....

Vai demorar entre [**6 e 8**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/185667) semanas.
Sendo que o conceito de "semanas" é segredo industrial da empresa.